# Trying to link to azure blob files on a cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, razor, azure-blob-storage

I've uploaded some jpg and txt files to an azure blob store and I've read [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) so I know how to retrieve them.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to load and link to the files when a link in my cshtml page is clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to download a file when user click a link in your .cshtml?

Comment: @Overmachine that would be fine, although the file opening in the a new tab would be preferable.

Comment: @viperguynaz I don't really know how to store the file in a way that makes it accessible in the webpage so I'm not sure what to try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know how to retrieve the files you know how to load them, you can set up something very simple like this.

**the ViewModel which is going to represent the data that you want to display on your view/page.**

```
public class FileViewModel 
{

  public string FileName {get; set;}
  public string AzureUrl {get; set;}

}
```

**The controller action**

```
public ActionResult ListFiles()
{

 var fileList = new List<FileViewModel>();

 //.. code to connect to the azure account and container

 foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
{
         if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
        //In case blob container's ACL is private, the blob can't be accessed via simple URL. For that we need to
        //create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token which gives time/permission bound access to private resources.
        var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),//Asssuming user stays on the page for an hour.
        });
        var blobUrl = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sasToken;//This will ensure that user will be able to access the blob for one hour.

           fileList.Add(new FileViewModel
            {
                FileName = blob.Name,
                AzureUrl = blobUrl
            });

        }
  }
 return View(fileList)
}
```

**the cshtml view**

```
@model IEnumerable<FileViewModel>


<h2>File List</h2>

@foreach(var file in Model)
{
  //link will be opened in a new tab
  <a target="_blank" href="@file.AzureUrl">@file.FileName</a>
}
```

This will only work if the Blob's container is public in this [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2/) explain how to create and use private blob containers. thanks to **GauravMantri** who pointed that out.

Comment: What would happen if the blob container's ACL is private? It would be better to give out a SAS URL with Read permission instead of blob URI.

Comment: @GauravMantri yes, this will only work if the container is public, is based on the provided link http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: @GauravMantri not at all, go for it